# How do we create funny segwit v1 taproot bech32m addresses?

Tags: vanity-address, p2tr, bip350-bech32m

Look at [what this user has broadcasted](https://mempool.space/tx/972f97a66cd5dc4ab38903b0ff84607c61d8f4206bd30ec2d31f76c23c7d76c9), destination addresses are interesting:

> bc1pjjjkkkklllllmmmmmmnnnnnnnpppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrraq663x0t
> bc1pttttuuuuuvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyys8888888888sqhaesl3
> bc1paaacccdddddeeeeeefffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhhhh77777777q890057
> ...

How fun?
Care to explain this wizardry, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These outputs are not spent, so quite possibly, they're addresses that nobody has the private key (and/or scripts) to.

If so, that's trivial: put whatever string you like in the non-checksum part of the address, and compute the corresponding checksum.

Comment: And they burnt ~2 m₿ on that [0.o]